# What is the difference between Unity-2D and Unity-3D?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

What is the difference between Unity-2D and Unity-3D? Would unity-2D be supported (updates, features) in the future version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technical differences.

### Unity

- Written in C++ as a compiz plugin and [uses nux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18413/what-is-nux-and-whats-it-used-for) for OpenGL support.
- Requires hardware acceleration (Compositing). ([Hardware requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements))
- Is shipped as the default environment in 11.04
- Also does window management via compiz itself.

### Unity 2D

- Written in C++ with Qt
- Works on systems without hardware acceleration, like ARM-based platforms, as a result it is incapable of advanced 3D effects.
- Shipped as the fallback method in 11.10. Is not shipped by default in 11.04, available as a separate package that the user has to install.
- Needs a seperate window manager (like metacity) to do window management.

Answer (score 1):

Unity-2D is for use with computers that do not support 3D-accelerated graphics, such as some low-end netbooks. Unity-2D looks almost exactly the same as its 3D counterpart, albeit without a bit of the eye-candy.

As for updates, both should be updated around the same time - although I'll expect Unity-3D will have a bit more effort put into it just due to the fact it is the "mainstream" version of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

unity 2D started from net books and was new i used it on my net books unity 3D will be The default for 11.04 if 3D is supported there are added features for instance if you open a web browser and maximize the bar will hide.