# Difference between Unity and 2D

Tags: unity, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)

I can't tell the difference between 2D and Unity(3D?) when I log in with the trial LiveCD. How can I tell which one I am using and if I am using compiz ok?

Comment: Possible duplicates - http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d and http://askubuntu.com/questions/34913/what-is-the-difference-between-unity-2d-and-unity-3d

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

If the output is `ubuntu` then you're running Unity; `ubuntu-2d` otherwise.

Comment: WoW! I would have never guessed!. It says ubuntu. Ubuntu is for Unity and ubuntu-2d is for...? But it looks exactly the same . I can not tell the difference. Maybe the value of $DESKTOP_SESSION only stores my choice when I logged in. But that I know. What I don't know is what has become effective. If I am running compiz or not. If I am using all the features or I am missing most.

Comment: @Robert: this is rather obvious, but if I understand your question correctly, you can run `ps x | grep compiz` to see if compis is running.