# What is Unity 3D / 2D?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 'Ubuntu Unity' (for the Desktop)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10031/what-is-ubuntu-unity-for-the-desktop)

I haven't used Ubuntu since like version 9 or something. Now that I just downloaded and installed v12, I want to know what all the talk about "Unity 3D" is about? Am I right to assume that Ubuntu now uses **the** [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)? And am I right to assume that Unity is just the theming scheme of Ubuntu? (Pretty much like Aero on Windows 7?)

Comment: You'll be able to find your answers at [What is 'Ubuntu Unity' for the desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10031/what-is-ubuntu-unity-for-the-desktop) and [What is the difference between Unity 2D and Unity 3D](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34913/what-is-the-difference-between-unity-2d-and-unity-3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *am I right to assume that Unity is just the theming scheme of Ubuntu? (Pretty much like Aero on Windows 7?)*

"Unity" is Ubuntu's default desktop environment, like the old Gnome and KDE you may remember. In a very simplistic way, sure, it's a "theming scheme" like Aero.

> *Am I right to assume that Ubuntu now uses the Unity 3D?*

No, Ubuntu's Unity has *nothing* to do with the *Unity 3D* gaming engine.

- Just Unity usually refers to Unity 3D, which is prettier but requires a reasonably modern video card; Unity 2D is the version for low-end computers.
- If you prefer the "classic" pre-9.10 Ubuntu experience, try installing the `gnome-session-fallback`, which will show up on your login screen as *Gnome-Classic*
- For lots more info on Unity and pretty pictures, see http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/