# Why doesn't the Dash have an overlay scrollbar?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash, overlay-scrollbars

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. The overlay scrollbar doesn't appear in the dash when i hover over the scrollbar. It appears in other places.

Comment: This isn't an issue, this is just part of Ubuntu, I suggest that if you feel overlay scrollbars are needed in the dash I suggest that you visit http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ and submit it as an idea. :)

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 2):

#### It's a known bug/"feature" in Nux

I believe this is what you mean (see circled cursor):

[image]

---

This is a [known bug/feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/608124), with no estimated fix date (it's in the backlog).

- The situation and bug report are very complicated because the bug was originally filed in 2010 when Unity was still 2D; that was fixed, but it's still a problem in the new Unity 3D interface.

  - Overlay scrollbars work everywhere else because applications use GTK+; **but** not for the Dash because it uses [Nux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18413/what-is-nux-and-whats-it-used-for) instead.
- To expedite a fix, I recommend filing a *new* bug, explicitly linking to the old one and emphasizing that this is only for the new Unity 3D dash using Nux.

#### Workarounds

- Try to not even need scrolling by using the Filter to reduce the displayed results.
- Use the up/down arrow keys instead

Answer (score 0):

Okay! i found a satisfactory work around to the question I posted.Here is the answer.Maximize the dash window and use the mouse on the scroll bar then its hard to miss the target.