# Is there any documentation for Nux?

Tags: unity, application-development, nux

I'm considering writing somethings that could benefit from running like Unity. I know Unity uses the Nux toolkit for drawing itself but I can't find any documentation about it.

Is there a helpful little website somewhere that explains how non-Canonical people can use Nux, or do I have to pull Unity apart and learn that way?

Comment: refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/18413/what-is-nux-and-whats-it-used-for

Comment: I have this gem: http://inalogic.com/component/content/article/35-nux/49-nux-and-unity a 5-parter blog about Nux.

Comment: Also there [Building NUX](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/#build-nux) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closes I got to anything regarding tutorials, documentation and examples:

[Nux examples](https://code.launchpad.net/~jaytaoko/nux/nux-samples).

You can add it to your system with

```
bzr branch lp:~jaytaoko/nux/nux-samples
```

I sure hope someone has better links ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/#build-nux has instructions for getting and building Nux