# Why was Qt chosen for unity-2d and Nux for 3d?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I would just like to know the reason(s) behind this decision (Pros./Cons. of using Qt and NUX). Thank you very much and keep on the awesome work! Ubuntu rocks! :D

Answer (score 2):

Nux wasn't exactly chosen - it was created from scratch and is developed alongside Unity. For some information on what it is and the benefits [see this posting from Unity developer Jason Smith](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16253/what-gui-toolkit-will-ubuntu-unity-use/17929#17929). Also there is a question that [goes into much more detail on the inner workings of Nux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18413/what-is-nux-and-whats-it-used-for).

Qt has recently been praised by [Canonical's Matt Zimmerman on his blog](http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/10/20/ubuntu-and-qt/) for being stable on ARM platforms as well as x86; for being cross platform; and for having a mature touch input system.

I know this doesn't completely answer your question but it gives some insight into reasoning behind these decisions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had already read the post from Jason Smith, but not the one from Matt. I have to agree with him regarding the strengths of QT. "It already powers popular cross-platform applications like VLC", so true... Well, once again, thank you!

Comment: Nux was created by one of the Unity developers because of his interest in game systems development - it's a raw GL toolkit, essentially. We adopted Nux for Unity as part of the move to Compiz in order to get closer to the GL capabilities of modern hardware, we found Clutter very restrictive in that regard for the first 3D version of Unity.